# Custom google maps marker via SVG path

Tags: google-maps, svg

I'm currently using a red circle as a google maps marker from a SVG path I picked up on another StackOverflow post.

```
new google.maps.Marker({
    map:map,
    icon:{
        path: "M-20,0a20,20 0 1,0 40,0a20,20 0 1,0 -40,0",
        fillColor: '#ff0000',
        fillOpacity: .6,
        anchor: new google.maps.Point(0,0),
        strokeWeight: 0,
        scale: 1
    }
});
```

[image: Current Map]

I'd like to revise this and draw my marker as an empty red square with white lat & long lines extending outward from the square's border, so it looks a bit more interesting, like this sketch from Adobe Photoshop:

[image: Target Map]

I'm not quite sure how to manipulate my current icon to achieve this result (for the two lines in white & one square in red, it seems like I would need 3 different icons, although I'm not sure how to extend the lines just to the edge of the map outward from the square's edge.)  Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If this was just a vanilla svg written in markup, your concept would require, at a minimum, 2 paths (you could do it with one if they were all the same color). But its unclear to me if this notation for defining an svg -

```
 icon:{
    path: "M-20,0a20,20 0 1,0 40,0a20,20 0 1,0 -40,0",
    fillColor: '#ff0000',
    fillOpacity: .6,
    anchor: new google.maps.Point(0,0),
    strokeWeight: 0,
    scale: 1
}
```

Would allow multiple paths. I would just try adding the extra path under the current one.

The easiest way to 'extend the lines' would just be to make them at least twice as long as the screen's width, so they would always be visible even when the icon is dragged to the extreme edges of the screen. Kind of a crude solution, but it would work (assuming google maps doesn't fix the viewbox attribute of the svg). The *proper* way to do it would involve svg filters and / or clip-path ( https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/clip-path ) but I doubt the google maps icon would allow such features.

Single path solution shown below -   Solution with a red square would be similar, just have the red square overlap the grey square part, and make the grey square part slightly 'thinner' so it wouldn't stick out from under the red

[image: single path solution]